# Object.defineProperty() default value with getter/setter

Tags: javascript

I am messing around with some "classical" inheritance and I'm running into an issue. I am using `Object.defineProperty()` to add properties to my `LivingThing` "class". I want to have a default value, along with a property getter/setter.

http://jsfiddle.net/fmpeyton/329ntgcL/

I am running into the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Invalid property.  A property cannot both have accessors and be writable or have a value, #<Object>
```

Why am I getting this error and what would be the best approach to have a default value and a getter/setter for a property, using `Object.defineProperty()`?

Comment: Depends. Are you using the setter to do anything special, or is the default value all the behavior you want?

Comment: The setter is just used to replace the old property value with a new value. I _believe_ this is the default behavior, though I'm not sure.

Comment: OK so you don't actually need a setter and getter ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a function scoped variable to back the defined property and set that variable's initial value to the default:

```
function LivingThing(){
    self = this;
    var isAlive = true;

    Object.defineProperty(self, 'isAlive', {
        get: function(){
            return isAlive;
        },
        set: function(newValue){
            isAlive = newValue;
        },
        configurable: true
    });

    self.kill = function(){
        self.isAlive = false;
    };
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/329ntgcL/5/

`writable` isn't necessary because you have a setter.  That's what's causing your error.  You can either have value/writable (data descriptor) OR get/set (accessor descriptor).

As a result, when you call `var l = new LivingThing`, `l.isAlive == true` and after you call `l.kill()`, `l.isAlive == false`

Comment: In this case, what would be the purpose of defining a property of the instantiated object when we are ultimately just using a functionally scoped variable?

Comment: You could very well just use a `this.isAlive` / `self.isAlive` variable.  The purpose of a getter/setter would be if you want to manipulate the values being set/got from the value that is actually stored.

Comment: For example, if you wanted `isAlive` to act like a String but be stored as a boolean, you could have `get: function(){ return isAlive ? "yes I'm still alive!!" : "..."; }`.  It could also be used for more complex manipulations.

Comment: It's also good for input validation/conditioning (i.e. `if ([true, false].indexOf(newValue) == -1) throw "Value must be true or false";` or `isAlive = Boolean(newValue)`)

Comment: When you mention that "I could use `self.isAlive`" you don't mean within the getter right? Since this would cause an infinite loop/max call stack. How would you implement `self.isAlive`?

Comment: As you currently have your code, the use of `defineProperty` doesn't serve much purpose.  The code in my answer is valid, but you could just have a raw property `self.isAlive` with the same effect.  If you're not planning to do anything special with the getter/setter, why are you using `defineProperty` instead of a simple field access / declaring the property directly on the object?

Comment: No good reason. I was merely messing around with `Object.defineProperty()` for better understanding.

Answer (score 2):

Your getter/setter pair presents a computed property, you can (and should) back that up with a real property if you need storage:

```
self._isAlive = true;
Object.defineProperty(self, 'isAlive', {
    get: function(){
        return this._isAlive;
    },
    set: function(newValue){
        this._isAlive = newValue;
    },
    writable: true,
    configurable: true
});
```

Presumably, put some logic there to justify a setter/getter vs a regular property. Setters are for wrapping property access.

Answer (score 2):

Without a setter and getter, you can define a default value by just assigning it to the prototype:

```
LivingThing.prototype.isAlive = true

var o = new LivingThing()

console.log(o.isAlive) // true
```

Just to be clear, changing that property on an instance of LivingThing will create a property for that instance, not change the value in its `__proto__`.

```
o.isAlive = false

console.log(new LivingThing().isAlive) // still true
```

Comment: Follow up question: what would necessitate the need for a setter/getter? I assumed this would be whenever a property was accessed/written.

Comment: There are a few typical scenarios. One is if you have an internal value that is not in a format expected by some context where the object is used. Another is so you can apply side-effects or validation. Another is a truly computed property such as "length" where you'd only have a getter.

Comment: Since you're already aware of Object.defineProperty, you know that you don't need a getter/setter to make a property readonly, which used to be one other use case.